# Git - Can't connect to my website

Tags: git, bash, web

Hello I am getting the error

```
"ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"
```

This is after I attempted to log into my server with the wrong password a few times. I was logging in with

```
 ssh username@website.com
```

and then i am suppose to be asked for a password but now i have an error.

I am using git bash for windows and the server is on Godaddy.

I have connected from another computer/ip address and it is fine so i think i am being blocked by my ip address or a file on this computer or the website is blocking me.

i've seen people say that "some how (they got) locked out (of) localhost with denyhosts"

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using godaddy as a host. I just had to contact them and tell them to whitelist my IP. That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably `fail2ban` or something similar running on your server, blocking your IP address after a couple of failed logins.

Solution is to log in from a different IP address, and remove your IP address from the fail2ban cache.

Comment: ok, is the fail2ban cache a file on my server? or a command i have to run?

Comment: i tried "fail2ban-client set JAIL unbanip MYIP" but not a command .I am on gitbash . I don[t see a fail2ban folder